# Username difference between site collections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-property

In the root site collection of my SharePoint web application I see the username as `first name - last name`, but in other site collections the username is displayed as `DOMAIN\USERID`.

How can I change the settings so that all sites show the username as: `first name - last name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this Powershell script to do a Active Directory synchronisation:

```
Get-SPUser –Web http://<URL> | Set-SPUser –SyncFromAD
```